# How to read a double value with a certain precision

Tags: java

How to read a double value from a String with a certain precision (say 4) assuming the string contains something like "10.1234" using this [api](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want decimal precision, **`double` is the wrong target type**, as it is a binary format that cannot accurately represent most round decimal fractions. That `double` value will actually be rounded to something like 10.123399999999999999976

Instead, use `BigDecimal` all the way, or forget about runding while you read and manipulate the data, and round it only when you print the result.

[Read The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(new Double(new BigDecimal("10.123456789").
        setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN). // choose precision and specify rounding policy
        doubleValue()
        ));

>> run:
10.1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

Math.round(number*100)/100

to get the precision, but this will probably not do what you want due to the internal representation of floats and doubles.

If you really need to work with a fixed number of digits after the decimal point consider using BigDecimal.

For formatting output you can use the C-like printf functionality as decribed in [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/sprintf/). It is not pretty but practical.

Comment: Or you could just use BigDecimal. There is no good reason to use the "calculations in cents" hack when you have a proper decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your String also contains letters.
You can parse the number out of the String first:

```
String numberString = ...
int precision = ...

int index = numberString.indexOf(".");
numberString = numberString.substring(0, index+precision+1); // Maybe without "+1"
Double number = Double.valueOf(numberString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to truncate the `String` to at most 4 digits following the decimal point, then use `Double.valueOf`.

```
        String[] tests = {
            "12",
            "12.",
            "12.3",
            "12.34",
            "12.345",
            "12.3456",
            "12.34567",
            "-123.45678",
            "1.23456.789.0",
        };
        for (String test : tests) {
            String truncated = test.replaceAll("(\\.\\d{4}).*", "$1");
            System.out.printf("%15s %15s %15s%n",
                test, truncated, Double.valueOf(truncated)
            );
        }
```

This prints:

```
             12              12            12.0
            12.             12.            12.0
           12.3            12.3            12.3
          12.34           12.34           12.34
         12.345          12.345          12.345
        12.3456         12.3456         12.3456
       12.34567         12.3456         12.3456
     -123.45678       -123.4567       -123.4567
  1.23456.789.0          1.2345          1.2345
```

#### How the regex works

It captures a literal `.`, followed by up to four digits `\d{4}`, into `\1`. It also matches everything else that may follow `.*`, and replaces the whole thing with `$1` (backreference to what `\1` captured).

The advantage of this over, say, a simple `indexOf` approach is that it works even when there aren't 4 digits, or even when there isn't even a decimal point at all, without requiring special treatment.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [Java Tutorials/Regular expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)